# php if and else if statement from a sql value

Tags: php, sql

I have a query like so:

```
if ($auto_hold = sql::value("select a.code, a.primcode, b.secondary_auto_hold from ev.do.nt_dg_li() a
                         left outer join eve.do.nce_data b on a.seccode = b.CODE_
                         where primcode like 'INSM%%' and secondary_auto_hold = 1 and code='$patient_id'"))
```

if my variable matches that query than i want to echo an alert if it doesn't than it should do nothing.

easy question but i'm drawing blanks atm. any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I've tried various assignment operators ie. ==, === but nothing.

I'm sure i could probably drop the variable as well and just say if(sql::value etc)

I figured it out:

```
if ($patient_id == $auto_hold) echo "<div class='patient_alert_red'>Auto hold on deductible for this patient.</div>";
```

Comment: Have you tried using `var_dump` to see what it's actually returning? This will give you a better idea of what to expect.

Comment: it's returning the id which is correct for the parameters associated with the query. The id for the person's account i'm on.

Comment: @Supplement please post your solution as an answer and accept your own answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is as follows:

```
if ($patient_id == $auto_hold) echo "<div class='patient_alert_red'>Auto hold on deductible for this patient.</div>";
```

I used the == / Equal operator to verify they're the same.

More here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp